# DataBinding a DropDownList in ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm extremely frustrated trying to switch to MVC after a couple years of webforms development.

Here's my extremely simple problem that I can't manage to solve:
I have a list of States in a table called StateProvince.
I have a DropDownList.
I want the DropDownList to display all of the States.

Keep it simple, I know nothing about MVC.

Here's what I have. All this gives me is a DropDownList filled with "System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem".

Action:

```
  public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var dbTimecard = new TimecardDbDataContext();
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> stateProvinces = dbTimecard.StateProvinces.Select(p => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = p.StateProvinceId.ToString(),
            Text = p.Name
        });
        SelectList theList = new SelectList(stateProvinces);
        ViewData["StateProvince"] = theList;
        return View();
    }
```

View:

```
<div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.StateProvinceId) %>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StateProvinceId, (SelectList)ViewData["StateProvince"])%>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StateProvinceId) %>
            </div>
```

Comment: is the Model.StateProvinces actually filled with objects AND the StateProvinceId contains a non-null value AND the model != null?

Comment: Can you show the action?

Comment: Ok I assume Create is your GET... where is the code that handles the post and returns the result? That is where I think the problem is and ViewData is not persisted between calls but I could be totally misinterpreting the question.  Is the problem on initial load or after you post your results and are rebuilding the view?

Comment: Yes, this is the GET. Forget the POST. I shouldn't even have mentioned the POST. I can't even populate the DropDownList. How do I populate the DropDownList? Allow me to clarify: I want a DropDownList to show some values from a Database. How do I make this happen?

Comment: I know MVC can be hard to get your head around, but keep at it! It's well worth it once you figure out how things work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I was looking for:

Action:

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var dbTimecard = new TimecardDbDataContext();
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> stateProvinces = dbTimecard.StateProvinces.Select(p => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = p.StateProvinceId.ToString(),
            Text = p.Name
        });
        ViewData["StateProvince"] = stateProvinces;
        return View();
    }
```

View:

```
<div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StateProvinceId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["StateProvince"])%>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StateProvinceId) %>
            </div>
```

Comment: There is no model being assigned to the view so how is `model => model.StaeProvinceId` suppose to work?  Check out the edit I made to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing this

```
SelectList theList = new SelectList(stateProvinces);
```

with this...

```
SelectList theList = new SelectList(stateProvinces, "Value", "Text");
```

Answer (score 0):

Common browsers don't support `PUT` verb within HTML forms. You might need to handle this using ajax:

```
$(function() {
    // when some button is clicked:
    $('#someButton').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/controller/action',
            data: { selectedState: $('#StateProvinceId').val() },
            type: 'PUT',
            success: function(data) {
                alert('state successfully submitted');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I actually meant POST.

Answer (score 0):

When the data is posted, the items listed in the `DropDown` are not posted back to the model so I am assuming you are not fetching them again and re-adding them to your model before returning your model back to the view.

You need to make sure on your post that you are filling `Model.StateProvinces` and then passing it to your View.  Only the values are persisted unlike WebForms which would maintain the `DropDownList` items in the `ViewState` and rebuild them for you.

So assuming your controller looks something like:

```
// POST: /YourController/YourAction/{ID}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourAction(YourModel model, int id)
{
    // model.StateProvinceId has the selected value

    // you need to fill StateProvinces since it is empty as the list is not posted
    // back so it is not autofilled into your model.
    model.StateProvinces = LoadYourStateProvincesList();

    // This would blow up if StateProvinces is null because your View is assuming that
    // it has a valid list of StateProvinces in it to build the DropDown
    return View(model);
}
```

I actually asked a question a while back that might be of some use to help explain how to handle DropDown lists:

[Best way of implementing DropDownList in ASP.NET MVC 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398296/best-way-of-implementing-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc-2)

**EDIT:** Based on your comment it you are not even getting the first list up... well it looks like you might not have your model setup correctly.  Do you even have a model?  Your create is just returning `View()` with no model data in it.  You need to create a Model and return it.

Eg.

```
public class YourModel
{
    public int StateProvinceId { get; set; }
    /// ... whatever else you need
}

// Then in your view your controller you need to set it and create it
View(new YourModel() { StateProvinceId = 123 };);
```

You need the model so that when the form IS posted back you can retrieve the value because MVC will stuff the value into your model like th example I posted above regarding the POST part.

**EDIT:** Ok now that question is clearer and a lot simpler than the original question was making the problem out to be.  The problem is your SelectList needs tell it which fields to put where:

```
SelectList theList = new SelectList(stateProvinces, "Value", "Text");
```

In your original question you had:

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StateProvinceId, new SelectList(Model.StateProvinces, "StateProvinceId", "Name") )%>
```

Which was totally correct but it was how you were building up Model.StateProvinces that was wrong so it threw me off thinking it had to be something else.

Comment: How can I accomplish the following: Make the DropDownList display a list of the rows in the StateProvince table with the Text shown in the DropDownList being the column "Name" and the Value being the column "StateProvinceId".

Comment: I mean, I'm not even to the point of attempting to POST data yet.

Comment: I'm using a modelbinder for the POST.

Comment: @Daniel Coffman did you ever get this worked out?  If this or another answer helped you make sure to mark the accepted answer.