# MVC Dropdown List isn't binding to the model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I am trying set up a simple dropdown list but I dont seem to be able to get it to bind to the Model.
I am using Asp.Net MVC and nhibernate.

My dropdown list is declared like so:

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Project, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Projects"], " -- Select -- ", new { name = "Project" })%>
```

I set up the select list like so:

```
ViewData["Projects"] = new SelectList(projectRepository.GetAll(), "EntityGUID", "Name", editEntity.Project);
```

This seems to bind the select list to the Dropdown fine, but the SelectedValue is not set.
it shows up as the default --- Select ---

Also when I save this data, the dropdown does not bind to the model, I have to manually set the object like so to save it:

```
entity.Project = projectRepository.GetById(new Guid(Request["Project"].ToString()));
```

I believe I have take the correct messures to have this item bind directly to my model.
Is there something I am missing here?

Many thanks for your time,
Rod

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OMG I found the problem........

It has taken me 3 days to turn:

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Aspect, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["AspectTypes"])%>
```

into:

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Aspect.EntityGUID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["AspectTypes"])%>
```

model.Aspect**.EntityGUID**
I had to bind the drop down to the objects guid, not the object itself.
Doh....Im feeling the pain, much work to catch up on.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: This problem with this is that it will only bind the ID property and not the text, right?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a hunch since your code looks good to me but I don't think you need to include the forth parameter when defining your `SelectList`.  Setting that field might be distrupting the normal flow of things (overriding your model binding) and I have never bound a `DropDownList` and had the `SelectList`'s `SelectedValue` set.

Try removing that and see how it goes.

```
SelectList(projectRepository.GetAll(), "EntityGUID", "Name");
```

Also [I asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398296/best-way-of-implementing-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc-2) a while back regarding how to implement `DropDownList` in MVC2 that you might find useful.

Comment: Thanks Kelsey, 
I'll check out the article.
The SelectedValue parameter was only my last attemp. On the whole I haven't used it.
I just set it to try to preselect the value in the edit form.
I think it may be an issue in my nhibernate mapping, not setting the child object.
I'll look down that route.

Comment: I get this error when I dont set Lazy loading to false in the nhibernate mapping.
Initializing[AgileThought.ERP.Domain.Property.Project#8260fd30-97e7-46f4-818a-689f1e65a91c]-Could not initialize proxy - no Session.

Comment: And when I try to edit it, I am getting the following Model Validation error.
The value 'fd38c877-706f-431d-b624-1269184eeeb5' is invalid.
This suggests its trying to push my GUID into the object.
Pulling my hair out...

Comment: I think I'll raise a Nhibernate question.
Thanks for you time.